# Mongodb aggregate unwind condition

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have  collections like

```
{
    "avlble_date": ISODate('2016-03-30T00:00:00.000Z'),
    "offers": [
        {
            "rangestart": 0,
            "rangeend": 12,
        },
        {
            "rangestart": 12,
            "rangeend": 24,
        },
        {
            "rangestart": 24,
            "rangeend": 504,
        },
        {
            "rangestart": 504,
            "rangeend": 2160,
        }
    ]
}
```

`Rangestart` and `Rangeend` columns store the hours. I would like to query the collection where `avlble_date` - current time and convert difference in hours and return results where `rangestart` and `rangeend` between difference in hours

```
datediff: { 
    $divide: [{ 
        $subtract: [ "$avlble_date", ISODate()]
        }, 1000*60*60
    ] 
}
```

I want the resultset returned  like

```
{"avlble_date": ISODate('2016-03-30T00:00:00.000Z'),
offers:rangestart:504,rangeend:2160} }
```

What is the best way to achieve the above result?

Comment: Can you please show us the expected result? Because for just doing a date based query and projecting a result set, an aggregation is a bit of a sledgehammer to crack a nut.

Comment: I require records that are between the datediff ex: between rangestart and rangeend 

considering the above data, only 1 record should be returned

{avlble_date:'2016-03-30', rangestart:504,offers:{rangestart:504, rangeend:2160} }

Comment: There are real flaws in your logic here. First of all you are subtracting the "current date"  from the stored date, which with the "current" being greater than the stored date would result in a negative number. I suspect you might have been trying to get the "milliseconds since epoch" which would instead subtract `new Date(0)`. But even then the number returned ( `405360` ) would be much larger than the values you are comparing to. We also note since `$group` seems entirely wrong for what you likely want. Better to explain the logic you are looking for, being the "why".

Comment: I am getting the difference between current time and avlble_date in hours, the variable datediff returns time difference in hours